# How to vectorize pdf to cdf function when applied to pandas column (elements are numpy array)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pdf

Given a pandas dataframe with a column named `pdf`.

Wherein the column `pdf` each element is a 1D numpy array representing `pdf`.

I do have a function `convert_pdf_to_cdf` which outputs `cdf` of size `k` irrespective of input `pdf` size?

Required result is a 2D matrix with len of `result == rows` in the given dataframe and `cols == k`.
an inefficient way to get the result is to apply as follows:

```
df.pdf.apply(convert_pdf_to_cdf).to_numpy()
```

Can the above functionality of applying the function over every element of the column be vectorized? I tried with numba but felt the element being a numpy array it wasn't compatible.

Example for input dataframe:

```
    pdf
0   [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]
1   [0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.35]
```

and expected output:

```
array([[0.25, 0.5 , 0.75, 1.  ],
       [0.3 , 0.5 , 0.65, 1.  ]])
```

Intention is to understand how to vectorize any function while apply on a column whose elements are a numpy array.

Comment: Will you please provide samples of your input and expected output dataframes, as text?

Comment: `.apply` is the vectorized way of doing it, there is nothing more to do here. If the question is how to vectorize internals of `convert_pdf_to_cdf`, please post its code.

Comment: Performance gains from vectorization might be limited because `dtype` of `df.pdf` is `object`. If you started with a matrix instead (e.g. `df_pdf = df.pdf.apply(pd.Series)`, you could call `np.cumsum(df_pdf, axis=1)` and divide through by last column to get cdf.